# How to write assert for method returning interface method using Easy Mock?

Tags: return, assert, easymock

I am writing junit test case to test "getBaseLimit()" using EasyMock and TestNG. I am stuck at writing assert for line 1 in my test case.

NOTE: SingleLimit.java has many constructors with different paramters, so to avoid constructor chaining in my test case, I have Objenesis library of EasyMock.

```
//SingleLimit.java
protected Limit getBaseLimit()
{
    //body of method

   return Control.getBaseLimit(parameter1,paramter2,parameter3) //line 1
}

//Limit.java
public interface Control
{
    Limit getBaseLimit(final Object... additionalInputs);
}
```

**Any help would be highly appreciated**

Comment: Can you please provide a full test case? `Control.getBaseLimit` is static?

Comment: No, it is not static method.

Comment: question is highly unclear, can you simplify by providing more information